# Periodically restarting KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry to reload SSL context

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Our application is deployed to a k8s cluster, where TLS certificates are renewed quite aggressively, every hour. The application connects to Kafka as well, using mutual TLS authentication, which is configured in `application.yml`.

As far as I could tell, both the key- and truststore are loaded in an immutable way into the `SSLContext` and it can't be really replaced easily. Easiest, seemingly working solution may be restarting all the listeners, as the below code demonstrates:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry messageListenerContainer;

@PostConstruct
public void setupTlsCertificateRefresh() throws IOException {
    watch(() -> {
        log.info("Certificates have been renewed, restarting Kafka message listener container...");
        messageListenerContainer.stop();
        messageListenerContainer.start();
    });
}
```

Is there any conceptional problem with this approach? Is there a risk of possibly losing data due to the restart, especially during peak times?

Environment:

- Spring Boot 2.5.6
- Handler methods using `@KafkaListener`
- Manual ack
- Batch listener

*I know there is also [`SslEngineFactory`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=128650952) in `kafka-clients` but honestly that is way too complex to implement for such a small requirement, to reload the keystores...*

Answer (score 2):

Not only SSL options are immutable, but all the properties we pass to the `KafkaConsumer` are immutable and we cannot change them at runtime. So, we indeed have to destroy the current consumer and start a new one when we change those consumer options. Therefore restarting the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` is the right way to go. All the `MessageListenerContainer` are going to be stopped and cleared from the consumers. The next `start()` will initiate a new lifecycle for consumers.

When you have properties changed, you have to use a `MessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()` to modify props for the target consumers. The original properties are cloned in the ctor of listener container.

Comment: Thanks, @Artem Bilan! I had the same impression that this could be the right way to go. As for the property changes, I understand, however property values are not really changed in my case. Only the file content is changed, path to the key/truststores are not.